# Does Android broadcast an intent on OS updates?

Tags: android

I want to keep track of the user current OS version, does Android broadcast an intent on OS updates?

Comment: in few device I can see the notification's like update available.

Comment: Yeah but does the OS broadcast an Intent so you could setup a broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No but can't you just check it whenever you need it? Its a very simple procedure:

```
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
```